# Closure Compiler with Advanced Optimizations and Externs

Tags: javascript, compiler-optimization, google-closure-compiler

I have downloaded the latest closure compiler jar file and followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3) to see how I can get it to preserve references to JS functions defined elsewhere.

My test script, *hello.js* is as follows

```
function hello(nom)
{
 alert(nom + familyName());
}
```

My externs are defined in the file *externs.js*  which contains the code

```
function familyName(){}
```

I then issue the command

```
java -jar closure.jar --js hello.js --externs externs.js --js_output_file hello-compiled.js  --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
```

Without `ADVANED_OPTIMIZATIONS` everything works correctly - effectively a spot of code minification.  However, as soon as I put in the advanced flag the output `hello_compiled.js` comes out as an empty 1 byte file.  Clearly, I am misunderstanding something somewhere.  I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to put me on the right track here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your `hello.js` only defines the hello function?  If so, you need to add:

```
hello("foo");
```

so that something actually happens.  You can try this out with the [online closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).  The default code there is:

```
function hello(name) {
  alert('Hello, ' + name);
}
hello('New user');
```

If you comment out the last line and click the "advanced" button and compile, the result is successful but it is zero bytes.  This is because that code effectively does nothing, so the compiler is doing the right thing.

Comment: Well spotted and - now that you mention it - common sense.  I was asking the compiler to optimize and then expecting to see redundant code in the compiled, optimized output!